# Apache NiFi : How can i run a scheduled processor to remove files specified with a wildcard?

Tags: apache-nifi

I am using NiFi 1.9.2 on a Linux box
I want to a processor to run on a 30 sec timer to remove all files with a particular extension.
The configuration of the timer is no problem, setting that up in the Scheduling tab.

I have tried ExecuteStreamCommand, ExecuteProcess and  and have this problem with both of them:

Command rm

CommandArguments /home/dir1/dir2/file1.abc  (with and without -f)
the file is deleted successfully

I want to remove all files and tried using the wildcard *

When I set CommandArguments /home/dir1/dir2/*.abc nothing happens.

When I try to escape the * : /home/dir1/dir2/*.abc  NiFi reports an error 'cannot remove... no such file or directory'.
I get same error when I escape all the special chars.

I tried the same with FetchFile processor using File to Fetch field, and Completion strategy 'Delete File', and get the same problem.

How can I get NiFi to recognise the wildcard (*) or escape the special characters?

Answer (score 0):

I used a bash command.

So in ExecuteProcess for instance,
Command = bash
Command Arguments = `-c;"rm -f /home/dir1/dir2/*.abc"`
Argument Delimiter = ;
In the setting tab, tick the success box to automatically terminate relationship upon success. Note this swallows any returned error text such as 'cannot remove *.abc: No such file or directory'. The rm command itself is successful even though there are no files to remove.